# Module not found. Even though its is already present

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I am building a cart feature for a food ordering app.

The code for Cart.js is:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import ItemList from "./ItemList";
import { clearCart } from "../utils/cartSlice";

const Cart = () => {

    const cartItems = useSelector((store)=>store.cart.items);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleClear = () => {
        dispatch(clearCart());
    }

    return <div className="text-center p-4 m-4">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Cart</h1>
        {cartItems.length>0
        && 
        <button className="p-2 m-2 rounded-lg bg-black text-white" onClick={handleClear}>Clear Cart</button>
        }
        <div className="w-6/12 m-auto">
            <ItemList items={cartItems}/>
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default Cart;
```

For the line: `import { clearCart } from "../utils/cartSlice";`, I get an error saying `Cannot find module '../utils/cartSlice'`

I have used the same cartSlice in one of the other components, that's working absolutely fine.
The code for that component is:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { CDN_URL } from "../utils/constants";
import { addItem } from "../utils/cartSlice";

const ItemList = ({items}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleDispatch = (item) => {
        dispatch(addItem(item));
    }

    return <div>
            {items.map((item) => (
                <div key={item?.card?.info?.id} className="p-2 m-2 border-gray-200 h-40 border-b-2 text-left flex justify-between">
                    <div className="w-9/12">
                        <div className="py-2">
                            <span>{item?.card?.info?.name}</span>
                            <span> - ₹ {item?.card?.info?.price ? 
                                item?.card?.info?.price/100
                                : 
                                item?.card?.info?.defaultPrice/100
                                }
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <p className="text-xs">
                            {item?.card?.info?.description}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-3/12">
                        <div className="absolute">
                            <button 
                            className="mx-10 mt-[4rem] rounded-lg bg-black text-white shadow-lg p-2"
                            onClick={()=>handleDispatch(item)}
                            >
                                Add +
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <img src={CDN_URL + item?.card?.info?.imageId}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ))
            }
    </div>
}

export default ItemList;
```

The code for cartSlice is:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: {
        items: [],
    },
    reducers: {
        //addItem is action, and the function is the reducer function.
        addItem: (state, action) => {
            //it will modify our "state" based on the "action".

            // we're mutating the existing state here.
            state.items.push(action.payload);
        },
        removeItem: (state, action) => {
            state.items.splice(action.payload,1);
        },
        clearCart: (state) => {
            state.items.length = 0;
            // state.items=[]; => this will not work
        }
    }
})

export default cartSlice.reducer;

export const { addItem, removeItem, clearCart } = cartSlice.actions;
```

I checked spelling errors too, but it is all correct.
What could be the problem?

[The file structure is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jApR7.png)

Comment: Are you in windows? Share us the tree folder of your workspace

Comment: I have edited and added the link to the end.